# django error on importing class from model

Tags: django, import, model

I am trying to import a class from elements.models  that i need as foreignkey on another class. Problem is, i get a long error list that i don't understand. Without the line, everything works just perfectly fine.

The model where i import the line

```
from django.db import models
from elements.models import Region

class Character(models.Model):
    """ User characters that hold the personal game stats """
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    alive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, unique=True)
    xp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    alliance = models.ForeignKey('Alliance', null=True)
    credit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    bullets = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    hitpoints = models.IntegerField()
    accuracy = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

the elements.models Region class:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    """ type of booze and their base price """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=31, unique=True)
    alliance_slots = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now when I try to sync the database i get the following errorlist

http://pastebin.com/Y5kETg8b

any idea what causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be having circular imports. You are importing the Region class in the models.py file containing your Character class while importing the Character class in the models.py file containing the Region class.

Try replacing your Character class with this

```
from django.db import models

class Character(models.Model):
""" User characters that hold the personal game stats """
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
alive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=63, unique=True)
xp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
region = models.ForeignKey('elements.Region')
alliance = models.ForeignKey('Alliance', null=True)
credit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
bullets = models.IntegerField(default=0)
hitpoints = models.IntegerField()
accuracy = models.FloatField(default=0)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: Thanks!,  yes not sure how the circular import worked,  never had this before, but indeed replacing to elements.Region worked perfectly fine :)